# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{3y}^{3} e^{x^2} \, dx \, dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{3y}^{3} e^{x^2} \, dx \, dy.$$

---

Can you give me a hint because I can't figure it out how to integrate $\int e^{x^2} dx$.

Comment: You can't integrate $e^{x^2}$. Have you tried integrating wrt $y$ first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Tonelli's theorem, you can interchange the order of this iterated integration:
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1\int_{3y}^3 e^{x^2} dx dy \\
= & \int_0^3 \int_0^{x/3} e^{x^2} dy dx \\
= & \frac{1}{3}\int_0^3 xe^{x^2} dx \\
= & \frac{1}{6}\left.e^{x^2}\right|_0^3 \\
= & \frac{1}{6}(e^9 - 1).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of integration.